# How to change color by clicking on the chart bar?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, chart.js

I was able to do the color change effect with the onclick function, however I should follow the following logic:

1) The last bar will always come in a different color from the others .. For starting the chart it is like the first bar clicked.

2) When clicking on the other bars the colors must be changing, to show to the user that the bar was clicked, however the previous bars should return to their normal color ..

I'm having difficulty with this logic, and I'm using chartjs 2.x

```
class ChartVenda {
    constructor(_id, _dataJSON){
        this.id           = _id;
        this.dataJSON     = _dataJSON;
        this.chartElement = document.getElementById(_id).getContext('2d');
    }

    set chartObject(_object){ this.object = _object; }
    get chartObject(       ){ return this.object;    }

    get labels(){
        return ['jan', 'fev', 'mar', 'abr', 'mai', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'set', 'out', 'nov', 'dez'];
    }

    get bgColors(){
        return [
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            'rgb(202, 216, 229)'
        ]
    }

    get borderColors(){
        return [
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
        ]
    }

    createChart(){
        this.generateChart();
        this.addChartOptions();
        this.addDataJsonInChart();
        this.addChartLabels();
        this.addChartDatasets();
        this.addAnimation();

        this.chartObject.update();
        console.log(this.chartObject.data.datasets)
    }

    generateChart(){
        let chartVenda = new Chart(this.chartElement, { type: 'bar'});
        this.chartObject = chartVenda;
    }

    addDataJsonInChart(){
        this.chartObject.data.dataJSON = this.dataJSON;
    }

    addChartLabels(){
        let counterLabels = 0;
        this.dataJSON.records.forEach( () => {
            counterLabels += 1;
            this.chartObject.data.labels.push(this.labels[counterLabels-1]);
        });
    }

    addChartDatasets(){
        let arrDeltaVendam2 = [];
        this.dataJSON.records.forEach( (_item) => {
            arrDeltaVendam2.push(_item['Δ% Venda m²']);
        });

        this.chartObject.data.datasets.push({
            label:           `ae`,
            data:            arrDeltaVendam2,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
            borderColor:     'rgb(202, 216, 229)',
        });

        this.chartObject.update();
    }

    addChartOptions(){
        this.chartObject.options = {
            responsive:          true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: { display:   false },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{ ticks: {display: false, fontColor: 'white'},  gridLines: {display: false, drawBorder: false} }],
                xAxes: [{ ticks: {fontSize: 15,   fontColor: 'white' }, gridLines: {display: false, drawBorder: false} }],
            },
            onClick: function(_event, _value) {
                let datasetIndex,
                    dataset;

                if (_value.length) {
                    this.chart.data.dataJSON.records.forEach( (item) => {
                        if(item['Competência'] === _value[0]._model.label){
                            const VENDA_METROS_TESTE = document.getElementById('primary-jumbotron-subtitle-indicator-m²'),
                                  VENDA_ABS_TESTE    = document.getElementById('primary-jumbotron-subtitle-indicator-abs');

                            VENDA_METROS_TESTE.innerHTML = `${item['Venda m²']} m²`;
                            VENDA_ABS_TESTE.innerHTML    = `${item['Venda']} abs`;
                        }
                      });

                      datasetIndex = _value[0]._datasetIndex;

                      // Reset old state
                      dataset = this.chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex];
                      dataset.backgroundColor = dataset.backgroundColor.slice();
                      dataset.backgroundColor = 'rgb(133, 222, 252)'; // click color
                  } else {
                    // remove hover styles
                    for (datasetIndex = 0; datasetIndex < myChart.data.datasets.length; ++datasetIndex) {
                      dataset = this.chart.data.datasets[index];
                      dataset.backgroundColor = dataset.backgroundColor.slice();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    addAnimation(){
        this.chartObject.options.animation = {
            duration: 1000,
            onProgress: function() {
                /** @description <CRIA O EFEITO DE TEXTO EM CIMA DAS BARRAS> **/
                const CHART_OBJECT = this.chart;
                CHART_OBJECT.ctx.font         = Chart.helpers.fontString('17', 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                CHART_OBJECT.ctx.fillStyle    = 'white';
                CHART_OBJECT.ctx.textAlign    = 'center';
                CHART_OBJECT.ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
                Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function (_dataset, _index1) {
                    Chart.helpers.each(CHART_OBJECT.getDatasetMeta(_index1).data.forEach(function (_bar, _index2) {
                        let centerPoint = _bar.getCenterPoint();
                        CHART_OBJECT.ctx.fillText(_dataset.data[_index2], centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y);
                    }), this);
                }), this);
            },
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your first point, but to address your second point:

The below snippet sets a default colour for each bar ('lightgrey'). When a bar is clicked all bars are set to their original colour and the clicked bar is set to 'red'. The benefit of this approach is that the starting colour of each bar can be different and will correctly toggle to 'red' and back.

```js
let background = ['lightgrey', 'lightgrey', 'lightgrey', 'lightgrey'],
  myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'series1',
        data: [7, 10, 8, 2],
        backgroundColor: background.slice() // using .slice here 'clones' the array.
      }]
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      onClick: function(e, elems) {
        if (elems.length) {
          elems[0]._chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.forEach((value, index) => {

            // set element to the original colour (resets all).
            elems[0]._chart.config.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[index] = background[index];
            if (index == elems[0]._index) {
              // set the clicked element to red.
              elems[0]._chart.config.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[index] = 'red';
            }
          });
          myChart.update(); // if you don't want the animation use 'myChart.update(0);' instead.
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

**Notes:**

- the legend uses the colours of the first point so when it's clicked the legend colour changes also.
- this only works on the first dataset (`elems[0]...datasets[0]`).